# Saving an editable table in txt file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this editable table.

How I can save all data in a txt file (modified or not modified)?

```js
var cell = null; //Focus Zero

function modify(obj) {
  if (cell == null) {
    cell = obj; //Create "Cell"
    obj.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='newtext' value='" + obj.innerHTML + "' onChange='save();' style='border:none'></input>";
    document.getElementById("newtext").focus();
  }
}

function save() //function for save the focus
{
  var nuovoVal = document.getElementById("newtext").value;
  cell.innerHTML = nuovoVal;
  cell = null;
}
```

```html
<TABLE border=2>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="modify(this);">Denzel Washington</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD onclick="modify(this);">Robert De Niro</TD>
  </TR>

</TABLE>
```

Comment: 1. Save where? Local PC or server? 2. If server, what language? PHP/other?

Comment: I think this is duplicated:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: Unless server - then Ajax would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modify function I used [**contenteditable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)...

And for .txt download I used Blob...

Hope this helps...

```js
var cell = null; //Focus Zero



$('#save-link').click(function ()
{
  var retContent = [];
  var retString = '';
  $('tr').each(function (idx, elem)
  {
    var elemText = [];
    $(elem).children('td').each(function (childIdx, childElem)
    {
      elemText.push($(childElem).text());
    });
    retContent.push(`(${elemText.join(',')})`);
  });
  retString = retContent.join(',\r\n');
 var file = new Blob([retString], {type: 'text/plain'});
  var btn = $('#save-link');
  btn.attr("href", URL.createObjectURL(file));
  btn.prop("download", "data.txt");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE border=2>
  <TR>
    <TD contenteditable="true">Denzel Washington</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD contenteditable="true">Robert De Niro</TD>
  </TR>

</TABLE>
<a href="#" id="save-link">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Jagadesh! Is it possible save in a multiple file txt with the single data of cells? Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific... And if the answer is right give it an acceptance so that more people will be helped...

Comment: I need of a file txt with the id of single cells. For example:

data.txt:

n1=Denzel washinghton
n2=Robert De niro

(Where n1,n2 are id of cells)